# Existe função "main()" em Python?

Tags: python, funções

Em algumas linguagens, como em C, temos a função `main()` que normalmente é o ponto de entrada padrão do programa. Existe algo similar em Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não existe no python uma função `main()` como no C. Contudo existe uma variável nativa chamada `__name__` (com dois underlines antes e depois).

No python temos os módulos que podem se executados de forma indepedente ou importados em outro script. Com a variável `__name__` é possível sabermos se o script está sendo executado por meio de uma importação ou de forma direta.

Se o script estiver sendo executado por meio de uma importação, então a variável `__name__` recebe o nome do módulo importado. Agora se o script estiver sendo executado diretamente, por exemplo com o comando `python script.py`, então a variável `__name__` recebe o valor `__main__`.

Nesse link tem informações mais detalhadas: https://blog.alura.com.br/o-que-significa-if-name-main-no-python/

Answer (score 10):

Não há uma função `main()` em Python, pelo menos não da forma explícita. O que temos é o `'__main__'` que é o nome do escopo do código executado em *top-level*, sendo que é definido em `__name__` o nome do modulo. O `'__main__'` é definido quando o script é executado do terminal interativo ou chamado pelo interpretador da linguagem.

Você pode obter um "comportamento parecido" com o `main()` da seguinte forma:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Isso vai impedir que o conteúdo do script seja executado quando for importado:

```
import meuscript
```

Assim tudo que estiver no bloco do `if` não vai ser executado na importação, a não ser que você faça:

```
from meuscript import main
main()
```

e chame a função `main()` diretamente.

Veja na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__).

Answer (score 6):

Python é uma linguagem de *script* então ela já começa existir. De uma certa forma existe, mas não da mesma forma que C. Não existe formalmente, o código que é encontrado que não está dentro de uma função é tido como uma função global, a entrada padrão é o *script* que você mandar executar, dali ele vai executando.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Falando em [ponto de entrada da aplicação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point), **Python não define uma função para tal**.

> Os programas são interpretados de cima para baixo, como é comum em [linguagens de script](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_script). <sup>[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Python)</sup>

Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794098/designing-a-program-entry-point-in-python